# How do I get continuous tags with HTML::TokeParser

Tags: perl

I have html that looks like this,

```
<div>
   <span>Text 
       <a href="example.html">ABC</a>
       <a href="example.html">DEF</a>
       <a href="example.html">HIJ</a>
       <a href="example.html">KLM</a>
   </span>
   <p class="Time">
   09/28/10 - 03:46 PM EDT</p>
</div>
```

I need to loop through the `<a>` tags between the `<span>` tags till I get the text from all of them. This keeps changing from time so I do not know howmany `<a>` tags would exist. I cant do a,

```
while ( $tag = $stream->get_tag('a') )
```

because it browses through the `<a>` tags in the entire file. How can I make it stop when continuous `<a>` tags end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while ( $tag = $stream->get_tag(qw( a /span )) ) {
  last if $tag->[0] eq '/span';
  ...
}
```

Another approach would be to get any tag, and stop if it isn't `<a>`:

```
while ( $tag = $stream->get_tag ) {
  last unless $tag->[0] eq 'a';
  ...
}
```

Comment: Sometimes, simple $stream->get_tag is returning an error `Can't use string ("</h2>") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use`  why?

Comment: @Rajesh, please post a new question showing the code that generates an error.  That error message should indicate the line where the problem occurs.  It's best if you can post a self-contained example script that exhibits the problem.